# What is the Meaning of Gen. 37:10 ?

Tags: genesis

Gen. 37:10 says, "**Shall I and thy mother and thy brethren indeed come to bow down ourselves to thee to the earth?**"(KJV)

Joseph had seen that his mother bowed down after her death.

Genesis 35:18 says Rachel died. Chapter 37 says Joseph had seen the dream as his father, mother and 11 brothers were bow down him.'

Is this the meaning of Gen. 37:10?

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! We're a little different here, please take the opportunity to read our [Site Directives](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) as it will help you in asking and answering questions, Thank you!

Comment: I extensively edited this question 1) To ask a question, 2) To refer it to a specific text. Feel free to change my edits, but consider our format in asking questions.  You may also want to consider [this question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/15606/2479) as a response to yours.

Answer (score 1):

In Genesis 37:7-8, Joseph tells his brothers a dream of rule and dominion, in which Joseph, standing supreme as ruler, is paid homage by his self-abasing brothers. Of course, they are angry at this, from a younger brother. Leon R. Kass points out, in *[The Beginning of Wisdom](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226425673)*, page 517, the phrase "even more” that describes how much they hate Joseph, is a play on words, using the verb yosef,  "to increase or add", the root of Joseph's name. The brothers hated Yosef very much (yosef):

> [Genesis 37:7-8](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-37/): For, behold, we were binding sheaves in the field, and, lo, my sheaf arose, and also stood upright; and, behold, your sheaves stood round about, and made obeisance to my sheaf. And his brethren said to him, Shalt thou indeed reign over us? or shalt thou indeed have dominion over us? And they hated him even more for his dreams, and for his words.

Then Joseph has another dream, which he tells his brother, then his father:

> Genesis 37:9-10: And he dreamed yet another dream, and told it his brethren, and said, Behold, I have dreamed a dream more; and, behold, the sun and the moon and the eleven stars made obeisance to me. And he told it to his father, and to his brethren: and his father rebuked him, and said unto him, What is this dream that thou hast dreamed? Shall I and thy mother and thy brethren indeed come to bow down ourselves to thee to the earth?

To make sure that the reader understands what this dream means, Genesis has the father interpret it for them. The sun and the moon represent Joseph's father and mother; the eleven stars represent his eleven brothers. The reader will soon see these dreams come true, when Joseph becomes the vizier in Egypt and all Joseph's brothers showed obeisance to him, although the story spares his parents this indignity.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to what Dick has presented by saying that Jacob did, indeed, esteem Joseph as lord.

Following Jacob's interpretation of Joseph's dream, Genesis records:

> And his brothers envied him, but his father kept the matter in mind.
>   **-- Genesis 37:11**

In fact, Jacob kept the matter in mind his entire life. Towards the end of Jacob's life, Genesis records:

> When the time drew near that Israel must die, he called his son Joseph and said to him, "Now if I have found favor in your sight, please put your hand under my thigh, and deal kindly and truly with me. Please do not bury me in Egypt
>   **-- Genesis 47:29**

The Hebrew, [מָצָאתִי חֵן](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=h4672+h2580&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1), rendered in English as "I have found favor", represents an expression of humility used by a person who considers himself a servant of the one he is addressing, i.e. his lord.

Further, it is also recorded a couple of verses on, concerning Jacob:

> Then he said, "Swear to me." And he swore to him. So Israel bowed himself on the head of the bed.
>   **-- Genesis 47:31**

Jacob "bowed himself", [וַיִּשְׁתַּחוּ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?strongs=H7812&t=KJV). This is not an expression depicting the manner in which Jacob died on his bed, but the act of a man who recognised and esteemed the one whom God had raised up as his saviour, and the saviour of his entire progeny. His mother would clearly have rendered him the same honour had she been alive to do so.